# How to display a certain view from layout in Picture in Picture mod in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I am trying to implement pip mode in android. There is a LiveStreamActivity which contains these elements: Header layout, VideoStream layout and custom popup that I show programatically. Their contexts are the same: LiveStreamActivity. When I enter pip mode LiveStreamActivity's root layout shrinks and fits in small pip screen. But I only want to show VideoStream layout.

I tried `setSourceRectHint` to achieve this but it does not work. Summary : How to show desired view (or views) in pip mode?

```
override fun onUserLeaveHint() {

            val visibleRect = Rect()
            mBinding.videoStreamLayout.getGlobalVisibleRect(visibleRect)

            enterPictureInPictureMode(PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
                .setAspectRatio(Rational(9,16))
                .setAutoEnterEnabled(true)
                .setSourceRectHint(visibleRect)
                .setSeamlessResizeEnabled(false)
                .build())
        

        super.onUserLeaveHint()
    }
```

[image: image that describes the situation]

Answer (score 0):

Override [Activity.onPictureInPictureModeChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean,%20android.content.res.Configuration)) or [Fragment.onPictureInPictureModeChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean,%20android.content.res.Configuration)) callback and change header and popup visibility.

```
override fun onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode: Boolean, newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig)

    if (isInPictureInPictureMode) {
        // Hide header and popup
    } else {
        // Show header and popup
    }
}
```